# A simple function needs to be implemented in 10 different ways

Tags: c, ruby

I need a function that could return 5 when given 7, and could return 7 when given 5. But conditional statements aren't allowed. 
I need it through 10 different techniques ( all without conditional statements ).

However, I've implemented in 5 different manners. If you help me write other 5, it would be a pleasure :)

```
int returner( int input ) {
    return 12 - input;
}


int returner( int input ) {
    if(input != 0) {
        return 35 / input;
    }
    return 0;
}


int returner( int input ) {
    return input ^= 2;
}


int returner( int intput ) {
    return ( 7 % input ) + 5;
}
```

And finally, in ruby

```
def returner(input)
    return ([5,7]-[input]).pop
end
```

Comment: There are an infinite number of math formulas that will yield the same value for the input of 7: these "variations" can be expanded ad  infinitum. However, consider what happens for all *other* input values ..

Comment: In any case, consider arrays/string indexes, hash keys, message names, and throw/catch (I'm not kidding). Also switch, unless that is also disallowed.

Comment: The 2nd implementation uses a conditional statement.

Comment: I think the second implementation can get away with that if statement since its only purpose is to stop a division by 0.

Comment: `int returner( int input ) {
    return ( input % 7 ) + 5;
}` When given 5 will return 10, not 7

Comment: Looks like homework to me.   _If you help me write other 5, it would be a pleasure_ -- of course it would, until you have to do them yourself on your exam.

Comment: @nhahtdh That conditional statement is to avoid `1/0` case. It has nothing to do with the algorithm of the function. Function works fine if you remove it, it is just a precaution.

Comment: @ArslanAli dear friend! I am done. Do you need any more? :) :)

Comment: I have a really nice (*and cheaty*) solution to solve the problem in an arbitrary number of ways, but sadly the question's been closed. :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is 5 more:

```
p RUBY_VERSION
require 'set'

def fun1(x)

 [5,7].to_set.delete(x).to_a[0]

end

p fun1(7)

def fun2(x)

 a = [5,7].to_set
 b = [x].to_set
 p a.difference(b).to_a[0]

end

fun2(5)

def fun3(x)

 a = [5,7]
 a.slice!(a.index(x),1)
 p a[0]

end

fun3(5)

def fun4(x)
 a = [5,7]
 a.delete(x)
 p a[0]
end

fun4(5)

def fun5(x)

 a = '57'
 a = a.rpartition(7.to_s)
 p a[a.index(7.to_s)].to_i

end

fun5(7)
```

*Output:*

```
"2.0.0"
5
7
7
7
5
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a great question, but I think there is a chance to learn some different ideas here. `i` stands for input. Try the following with `i=7` and then "anything else" as input. Note than none of these approaches use math on the input value.

*Note: these will need to be adapted to return the inverse* - that is left as an exercise.

Hashes. By default a failing lookup returns `nil`. A default value can be specified with [`Hash.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html).

```
h = {7: 5}
h[i] // 5 or nil

h = Hash.new(0)
h[7] = 5
h[i] // 5 or 0
```

[Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html) enumeration methods - learn them. Here we just count how many elements of a particular value (7) exist.

```
a = [7,7,7,7,7]
a.grep {|x| x == i }.count  // 0 or 5
// or more idiomatic
a.count(i)
```

Boolean operator chaining - the result of `&&` and `||` is the successful expression or the "least failing" expression.

```
i == 7 && 5        // false or 5
(i == 7 && 5) || 0 // 0 or 5
```

A perverse use of [throw/catch](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/tut_exceptions.html) and inline exception stuffing.

```
catch (:"7") do
    throw i.to_s.to_sym rescue nil;
    // only here if i is not 7 or convertible to "7" AND
    // there is no matching catch further up
    return 0
end
return 5
```

On a similar note, how to rewrite the division example without without an `if`. Of course, if the function domain is *only* {5, 7} then even this is not required as 0 can never be [valid] input - and invalid input is outside the method contract.

```
return (35 / i rescue 0)
```

Comment: Good techniques I am seeing from your answer, `+1` to you.

Comment: hi! why do you thing that question is not good..I think question is very good.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Because it's a task and not a focused question. It's not a *terrible* question, but it's also not refined enough and open to "how would you do this" reading.

Comment: hmm correct.... agree :)

Answer (score 1):

I can contribute two more method using logical operator and their sort-circuit behavior:

**First**, its myown:

```
int r(char x){
    (x == 7 && (x=5)) || ( (x == 5) && (x=7));
    return x;
}
int main(){
    printf("\n If r(5) then return = %d", r(5));
    printf("\n If r(7) then return = %d", r(7));

    printf("\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Run:

```
$ ./a.out 

 If r(5) then return = 7
 If r(7) then return = 5
```

**Second,** Some days back I saw this trick:

```
int r(char x){                      
    int l[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,7,0,5};
    return l[x];
}
```

**Third**: trick use as I used in first

```
int r(char x){
    (x > 5 && (x=5)) || (x < 7 && (x=7));
    return x;
}
```

**Fourth**:

```
int r(char x){
    ((x & 2) && (x&=~2)) || ( (!(x & 2)) && (x|=2));
    return x;
}
```

**Fifty**: your own XOR

```
int r(int x){
    x = (x & ~2) | (~x & 2) ;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Dear, do you really think `==` is not a conditional statement?

Comment: @ArslanAli no `==` a conditional operator I means compare for is-equals

Comment: @ArslanAli `==` is the equals operator. It tests for equality. `if` is one conditional statement (it's actually an expression in Ruby, but that's a digression). A conditional statement "does something conditionally", such as executing one branch or another, based upon the input - which is often the result of a comparison operator.

Comment: `return (x % 2 == 0)` It is a test for a number: either it is even or odd! What you say about it? It is not conditional?

Comment: @ArslanAli It is not a conditional statement. Consider if the code was replaced with `return TrueIfEven(x)` - is [calling] the `TrueIfEven` method a conditional statement? If such is considered a conditional statement then all code (or almost all code, including mathematical functions) are conditional statements, but this is not a practical classification. Instead, consider what Wikipedia says about [Conditional Statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(programming)).

Comment: Perhaps you are right, but I ain't getting you!
A conditional statement is one that never returns the same thing. It uses some kind of test to choose from given options. 
See `x = 3` : now x will always be 3. On the other hand, If I say `x = (x == 3)` Now, I have two possibilities:

Comment: Thanks! Yap, I was wrong. It is a comparison operator.

Comment: @ArslanAli updated answer with five techniques for `C`. hope you find helpful.